# SharePoint CSR attachment control on newform.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-server, client-side-rendering

I have created a SharePoint list forms form scratch using CSR.

this is the [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSR-code-samples-11-Fully-54ebcaa6) that i have followed.

Everything is working as expected without attachment.

But when i select attach file option from the ribbon and click on OK button, I am getting `Cannot read property 'insertRow' of null at OkAttach` error in console.

Can anybody please help me out with this. Or is there any other way that I can use to create attachment control/field on the form.

Comment: Check this - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/31a8cf62-db68-4fb8-8c15-3748c67eb989/add-attachment-button-to-a-custom-new-form-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: @GautamSheth I have gone through the link you have provided. But the issue still persist. Anyway thanks...

Comment: I used your code for a newform.aspx on a SharePoint online site but I do not get the "Attachments" field at all and throws error at ctx.Templates.Fields[fieldName](fieldContext). NOTE: I have the Allow attachments to list item set to enabled and also set the List to "Classic experience" in Advanced settings. Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks,
Bhargav

Comment: @user5657565 can you please tell me exactly what error message you are getting? That would be much helpful.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolved the above mentioned issue.

The issue i was facing is because I had not rendered the `Attachment` field for my custom form.

Refer below code for the same :

```
(function () {  

  var rows = {};
  rows.one = '<tr>' +
            '<td colspan="3">' +
                '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">' +
                    '<tbody>' +
                        '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' +
                                '{{First_x0020_NameCtrl}}' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                                '{{Middle_x0020_InitialCtrl}}' +
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>' +
                        '<tr class="labelRowBelow">' +
                            '<td>First Name<span class="required">*</span></td>' +
                            '<td>Middle Initial</td>' +
                        '</tr>' +
                    '</tbody>' +
                '</table>' +
            '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr><td>{{AttachmentsCtrl}}</td></tr>';  // is the the placeholder you need to add for the attachment  


    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render   
    var formTemplate = {}; 
    formTemplate.Templates = {}; 
    formTemplate.Templates.View = function(ctx){

        var formTable = "".concat('<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" id="idGFF">', rows.one, '</table>'); 

        //Replace the placeholders with the default sharepoint controls 
        formTable = formTable.replace("{{First_x0020_NameCtrl}}", getSPFieldRender(ctx, "First_x0020_Name"));
        formTable = formTable.replace("{{Middle_x0020_InitialCtrl}}", getSPFieldRender(ctx, "Middle_x0020_Initial"));
        .....
        .....
        .....
        .....
        formTable = formTable.replace("{{AttachmentsCtrl}}", getSPFieldRender(ctx, "Attachments")); // this is to replace the placeholder for attachment with the attachment field's html. 

        return formTable; 
    }; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(formTemplate); 

})();  


//This function code set the required properties and call the OOTB (default) function that use to render Sharepoint Fields  
function getSPFieldRender(ctx, fieldName) 
{ 
    var fieldContext = ctx; 

    var result = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function( obj ) { 
        return obj.Name == fieldName; 
    }); 

    fieldContext.CurrentFieldSchema = result[0]; 
    fieldContext.CurrentFieldValue = ctx.ListData.Items[0][fieldName]; 

    return ctx.Templates.Fields[fieldName](fieldContext); 
}
```

**After this modifications, try to use the attachment from the ribbon. it will work perfectly.**

Comment: The CTX does not contain Attachment on the listschema.Field. Is there any other setting that I missed? I was following the structure from https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSR-code-samples-11-Fully-54ebcaa6

Comment: @Thisisme.. I will check and let me know.. :)

Comment: Thank you very much.. I am stuck on attachments.. I am working on NewForm.aspx for a list.

Comment: make sure you have added placeholder for attachment in your HTML e.g.: `{{AttachmentsCtrl}}`.  And then replace the placeholder for attachment with the attachment field's html e.g. `formTable = formTable.replace("{{AttachmentsCtrl}}", getSPFieldRender(ctx, "Attachments"));`.  You can refer above code as a reference for `attachment` field. Try to do these changes and let me know if it worked or not...

Comment: Hi @Rohit, I did added the section for Attachments and I am getting an Typeerror error from jQuery as  **result[0]** is empty and I checked the **ctx.ListSchema.Field** and it is missing **Attachments**. If I comment the **formTable** for Attachments, all the controls load as expected.

Comment: can you share your code.....?

Comment: Was not able to add code in the comment so I added it as the answer...

Comment: @Thisisme.. Your code seems to be right. I don't see any problem here. This should work. Try to clear the browser cache and check again.

Comment: I cleared cache and still not working. I am not sure why the `ctx.ListSchema.Field` does not contain `Attachments` field. This is a Newform.aspx. The list settings does have allow attachments checked. I have disabled quick edit though. Enabling the quick edit does not help either.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {  
var rows = {};
rows.one = '<tr>' +
        '<td colspan="3">' +
            '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">' +
                '<tbody>' +
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' +
                            '<div>Form Status</div>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                            '{{StatusCtrl}}' +
                        '</td>'+
                    '</tr>' +
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' +
                            '<div>Request Type <span style="color: Red">*</span></div>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                            '{{RequestTypeCtrl}}' +
                        '</td>'+
                    '</tr>' +
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td colspan="2">' +
                            '<hr />' +
                        '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' +
                            '<div>Item Type <span style="color: Red">*</span></div>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                            '{{ItemTypeCtrl}}' +
                        '</td>'+
                    '</tr>' +
                '</tbody>' +
            '</table>' +
        '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr><td>{{AttachmentsCtrl}}</td></tr>';  // is the the placeholder you need to add for the attachment  
    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render   
    var formTemplate = {}; 
    formTemplate.Templates = {}; 
    formTemplate.Templates.View = function(ctx){

    var formTable = "".concat('<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" id="idGFF">', rows.one, '</table>'); 

    //Replace the placeholders with the default sharepoint controls 
    formTable = formTable.replace("{{StatusCtrl}}", getSPFieldRender(ctx, "Status"));
    formTable = formTable.replace("{{RequestTypeCtrl}}", getSPFieldRender(ctx, "RequestType"));
    formTable = formTable.replace("{{ItemTypeCtrl}}", getSPFieldRender(ctx, "ItemType"));
    formTable = formTable.replace("{{AttachmentsCtrl}}", getSPFieldRender(ctx, "Attachments"));

    return formTable; 
}; 

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(formTemplate); 

})(); 
function getSPFieldRender(ctx, fieldName) 
{ 
var fieldContext = ctx; 

//for (var i=0; i< ctx.ListSchema.Field.length; i++){
//  alert(ctx.ListSchema.Field[i].Name);
//}
var result = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function( obj ) { 
    return obj.Name == fieldName; 
}); 

fieldContext.CurrentFieldSchema = result[0]; 
fieldContext.CurrentFieldValue = ctx.ListData.Items[0][fieldName]; 

return ctx.Templates.Fields[fieldName](fieldContext); 
}
```