# How to make section headings in custom list form

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I am creating a long form for inserting data using a custom list. I would like to divide into sections with a heading to make it more user friendly.

This is the example of the form that I need to create.
[image: Example of sections heading]

At the moment, I can't use Sharepoint Designer or MS InfoPath due to permissions are not granted. Is that possible? Any solution or reference that I can refer to?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Script Editor/Content Editor webpart? If Yes, you can use custom JavaScript and CSS to customize the forms

Comment: @GaneshSanap can I know where can I insert the custom Javascript and CSS? I'm sorry for asking this question. I'm still new to Sharepoint.

Comment: There is also another way to customize the list forms using CLient side rendering. Refer this link - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms

Comment: Also You can refer code from this post where I did some customizations using client side rendering to list forms. Though original post is related to attachment issue but you can refer this code it is in working staae. link - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218197/sharepoint-csr-attachment-control-on-newform-aspx

Comment: Each list has some default forms (Display, New, Edit). For your requirements, you have to add your custom code on New and Edit form. generally form URLs are like: `siteUrl/lists/listName/NewForm.aspx` and `siteUrl/lists/listName/EditForm.aspx`